# Rechart - adding labels to charts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to learn how to use Rechart. The documentation says you can put labels on chart elements, and gives an example of how to do it using 'name' as the label data key.

I've tried to do that in my chart, but it doesn't work.

If i remove the 'label' from the  field, then no labels appear. If I keep it, then the only labels that display are the values on the pie chart wedges.

I have a Label with a data key of 'name' (per the docs) but it doesn't render on the chart.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {
  ResponsiveContainer, PieChart, Pie, Legend, Label, LabelList
} from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Group A', value: 400 }, { name: 'Group B', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group C', value: 300 }, { name: 'Group D', value: 200 },
];

export default class Example extends PureComponent {
  static jsfiddleUrl = '//jsfiddle.net/alidingling/6okmehja/';

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%', height: 300 }}>
        <ResponsiveContainer>
          <PieChart>
            <Pie dataKey="value" 
            data={data} 
            fill="#8884d8" 
            Label dataKey="name"    
            />
          </PieChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do you add labels to pie charts?

Comment: Have you tried using `nameKey` attribute to tell Recharts the name of each sector? Moreover, be sure to write `label` and not `Label` (indeed, the second refers to a React component, but I'm pretty sure it is a typo)

Comment: Hi - the rechart docs use uppercase 'Label':  http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Label

Comment: How would i use nameKey?  I tried:             Label namekey="name"    
but it doesn't work

Comment: I have also tried;             Label value="name"    
but it doesn't work

Comment: I have also tried lower case l as:             label nameKey="name"    
but it prints the data values as labels (as it does when you use the default)

Comment: I tried downloading prime react charts to use instead, but that has a config error that says: ./node_modules/primereact/components/chart/Chart.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/dist/Chart.js

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For others looking for an answer, this works:

Define a function to render you labels the way you want, some like:

```
let renderLabel = function(entry) {
    return entry.name;
}
```

Set the label prop to point to your function:

```
<Pie label={renderLabel} [ you other properties ]>
[ your content ]
</Pie>
```

Comment: This needs to go into samples.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for delay, I was finally able to come up with a solution, even if it's not pretty straightforward

```
const {ResponsiveContainer, PieChart, Pie, Legend} = Recharts;

const data = [{name: 'Group A', value: 400}, {name: 'Group B', value: 300},
                  {name: 'Group C', value: 300}, {name: 'Group D', value: 200}]

const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;

const renderCustomizedLabel = ({
  x, y, name
}) => {
  return (
    <text x={x} y={y} fill="black" textAnchor="end" dominantBaseline="central">
      {name}
    </text>
  );
};

const SimplePieChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer>
        <PieChart>
          <Pie data={data} fill="#8884d8" label={renderCustomizedLabel} nameKey="name"/>
        </PieChart>
       </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimplePieChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: why aren't you using the recharts Label method?

Comment: First of all, capital case `Label` is a component and not a method. The main reason is that Rechart's Label component is very poor regarding flexibility, and whenever you need a little bit more customization, you always end up writing your own custom label.

Comment: Ok - but how do you use the Label from Rechart. It might not be very poor for my use case. I'm trying to keep to the documents as much as I can when I use these tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a example for PieChartWithCustomizedLabel in http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel

or below code will help you

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {
  PieChart, Pie, Sector, Cell,
} from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Group A', value: 400 },
  { name: 'Group B', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group C', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group D', value: 200 },
];

const COLORS = ['#0088FE', '#00C49F', '#FFBB28', '#FF8042'];

const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
const renderCustomizedLabel = ({
  cx, cy, midAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, percent, index,
}) => {
   const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;
  const x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN);
  const y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN);

  return (
    <text x={x} y={y} fill="white" textAnchor={x > cx ? 'start' : 'end'} dominantBaseline="central">
      {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`}
    </text>
  );
};

export default class Example extends PureComponent {
  static jsfiddleUrl = 'https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/c9pL8k61/';

  render() {
    return (
      <PieChart width={400} height={400}>
        <Pie
          data={data}
          cx={200}
          cy={200}
          labelLine={false}
          label={renderCustomizedLabel}
          outerRadius={80}
          fill="#8884d8"
          dataKey="value"
        >
          {
            data.map((entry, index) => <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />)
          }
        </Pie>
      </PieChart>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo here - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/c9pL8k61/)

Comment: hi - no - this doesn't work to solve the problem i raised n the question. I've posted an answer that does work - to help others learn

Comment: your sending label={renderLabel} - renderLabel is function which return value for every object in array. 
const data = [
  { name: 'Group A', value: 400 },
  { name: 'Group B', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group C', value: 300 },
  { name: 'Group D', value: 200 },
];

the return value will be label 

Same as you mention in your answer

Comment: @WaseemRajaShaik is it possible to have the pie chart line label on a scatter chart with rechart?

i have an open question would be great if you could help